# devolver un char* por funcion

Tags: c++, estructuras, enum

```
enum Month{JANUARY=1,FEBRUARY,MARCH,APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OCTOBER,NOVEMBER,DECEMBER};
struct Date{
    int Day;
    Month month;
    int Year;
}; 

char* to_str_date(Date d){
     int i,j=0;
     int lista[8]={(d.Day/10),(d.Day%10),(int(d.month)/10),(int(d.month)%10),(d.Year/1000),((d.Year/100)%10),((d.Year/10)%10),(d.Year%10)};
     char *date="hola";
     for(i=0;i<8;i++){
         if(i==2 || i==4){
             date[j]='/';
             j++;
         }
         date[j]=char(lista[i]+48);
         j++;
     }
return date;
}
```

esta es una función que debería de recibir una estructura date {dia,mes,año} y devolver un char* con el formato "dd/mm/yyyy" .el problema es que cuando imprimo la cadena a esta le faltan los últimos 2 dígitos correspondientes al año, creo q el problema es porque no se reserva suficiente memoria para usar la cadena date, agradecería cualquier ayuda :).
y también note que si imprimo las variables dentro de la función esta devuelve una cadena vacía quisiera saber a que se debe eso, por que no le encuentro sentido...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varias cosas a notar.

```
char *date="hola";
```

Aquí `date` apunta a un **literal**, es un valor fijo asignado en tiempo de compilación. Intentar modificarlo puede causar problemas (*undefined behavior*).

Sería mejor hacer

```
char *date = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) *5);
strcpy(date, "hola");
```

La primera instrucción reserva espacio para el texto, la segunda copia "hola" en ese espacio. Tampoco está claro para qué necesitas asignar el valor "hola".

La segunda cuestión obvia es que estás definiendo el literal con una longitud de 5 chars pero luego quieres asignarle 11 caracteres. Al tener j mayor que 4, hacer `date[j]= ...` escribe en una posición de memoria no reservada, de nuevo *undefined behavior*.

Lo más sencillo es simplemente reservar el espacio necesario:

```
 char *date = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);
```

Y no hay que olvidarse que un string acaba con \0, así que hay que hacer

```
 date[10] = (char) 0;
```

Comment: hola, si lo del "hola" en realidad estaba probando otras cosas y se me escapo ahí, y lo de la función malloc me funciono de 10 no me había dado cuenta de usarla para eso. muchas gracias! muy bien explicado!